# Adding leading zeros to a number

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there was a way to add leading zeros to numbers when selected that are less than 4 characters and cast as a string.

I appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

Something like:

`SELECT PAD(CAST(last4 as string), 4) as last4 from numbers`

Desired output:

```
1 => 0001
100 => 0100
112 => 0112
15 => 0015
```

Comment: you've edited your question to **leading** zeroes in your example :-) Those you get with LPAD(), trailing ones you get with RPAD().

Comment: @VMai, got it, thanks! p.s. please don't shoot me down for editing the question for I am a good hearted man ;)

Comment: please edit the headline and the first line of your question too - so no one would be irritated that an answer that gives leading zeroes was the right one after being asked for trailing ones ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very near:

```
SELECT LPAD(last4, 4, '0') as last4 FROM numbers;
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad