# How to limit the input digits of numeric character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to limit the UserID to 5 digits only (00000-99999) and if the digit is less then 5 it will filled by zero (00001). I don't know how to do it, so can anyone please answer this question for me? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to limit the size like that in MySQL. You can add the leading zeroes with `LPAD()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547935/adding-leading-zeros-to-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the column to be `int(5) zerofill` (documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)).  This is not standard SQL, but it pretty does much of what you want -- except restrict the values.

I think what you do want can be specified as `decimal(5, 0) zerofill`.  This will limit the value to five digits and fill "blank" leading digits with zeros.

As note, `zerofill` doesn't seem to work on SQL Fiddle (see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b381)).  I don't have another version of MySQL handy right now to test whether or not it actually does work with `decimal`, although the documentation suggests that it does.